# Is this a fasciated poppy?

Tags: identification, poppy

Here's some poppies growing wild near me. They have some unusual petals: is this fasciation?
[image: Orange poppies with unusual petals]

Here's a normal-looking poppy plant next to the first one:
[image: Normal-looking poppy]

Comment: If you can, I recommend collecting seed from these unusual flowers (note that they may be sterile and not set seed, though). Growing the seeds next year would be very interesting, especially if they keep those flowers. If they do, you have a new variety or cultivar!